# Exchanging Order of Integration - Expected Value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that Y is a continue random variable with density *f(y)* that is positive only if y$\ge$0. If *F(Y)* is the distribution function, show that $E(Y) = \int_0^\infty yf(y) dy = \int_0^\infty 1-F(y) dy$.

Hint: If y > 0, y = $\int_0^y dt, $ and $E(Y) = \int_0^\infty yf(y) dy = \int_0^\infty [\int_0^y dt]f(y) dy$. Exchange the order of integration to obtain the desired result.

My approach: So following the hint, I have the following:

$E(Y) = \int_0^\infty yf(y) dy = \int_0^\infty [\int_0^y dt]f(y) dy = \int_0^\infty \int_0^y f(y)dt dy$. How exactly do I exchange the order of integration here?

Comment: *Draw* the domain corresponding to the integration limits.

Answer (score 0):

Integration by part gives

$\int_0^\infty (1-F(y))dy = \left.(1-F(y))y\right|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty y d(1-F(y))=0-0+\int_0^\infty y F'(y)dy$

If the expectation exists then $(1-F(y))y \to 0$ as $y\to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Write it as $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[t\leq y\right]f\left(y\right)dtdy$$
where $\left[t\leq y\right]$ denotes the characteristic function
of set $\left[0,y\right]$ with argument $t$.

Then:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[t\leq y\right]f\left(y\right)dtdy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[t\leq y\right]f\left(y\right)dydt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-F\left(t\right)\right)dt$$
since $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[t\leq y\right]f\left(y\right)dy=\int_{t}^{\infty}f\left(y\right)dy=1-F\left(t\right)$$